# imagemagick convert tiff degrades quality, how to prevent it?

Tags: images, conversion, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick convert to extract multiple tif images from a single tif file. But when I use the following command

```
convert image.tif single%d.tif
```

I get very low quality (sort of blurred) images. The files `single1.tif`, `single2.tif` and so on are of very low quality as compared to the quality of the images in the original image.tif file.
I then tried

```
convert -enhance image.tif single%d.tif
```

Still I got very low quality images in the output.

What should I do to get just images with original quality separated in multiple files?

Additional output is here:

```
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.

convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37680 (0x9330) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
convert: image.tif: invalid TIFF directory; tags are not sorted in ascending order. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37679 (0x932f) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: image.tif: unknown field with tag 37681 (0x9331) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory'.
convert: Depreciated and troublesome old-style JPEG compression mode, please convert to new-style JPEG compression and notify vendor of writing software. `OJPEGSetupDecode'.
```

Comment: Can you add (a link to a) sample multi-Page TIFF exhibiting the behaviour you observe? This should normally not happen...

Comment: Can you also please post the output of the following commands: `identify image.tif` and `identify single*.tif`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting to a lossless image type instead of outputting more TIFF files. AFAIK, ImageMagick avoids recompression at all costs; but since it's throwing warnings that the original file is using old style compression (TIFF Revision 6 JPEG prior to Technote 2) it may be recompressing them anyway causing lower quality.

Try a lossless format first; if that doesn't help you might have to use a different library to extract the frames.

```
convert image.tif single%d.png
```

or

```
convert image.tif single%d.bmp
```